# Checking for Developer Options/USB debugging in .NET MAUI

Tags: android, maui

How can we check if developer options for Android platform is on or off in .NET MAUI code, its required to to check for developer options/USB debugging for security reasons

Did not found any solution yet to check it in code

Comment: If there is a way to do this, it would be Android-specific code; put in Platforms/Android folder. Did you search for Android (not Maui) answers?

Comment: I found Android specific code, but could not make it workable in MAUI

Comment: Add to question your best attempt at converting it to Maui, and say exactly what went wrong (full text of error message, as copy/pastable text), or where you got stuck converting the code. Show the original Android code, and the Maui conversion attempt. And the link where you got the original.